# Get weekday/day-of-week for Datetime column of DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, dayofweek

I have a DataFrame `df` like the following (excerpt, 'Timestamp' are the index):

```
Timestamp              Value
2012-06-01 00:00:00     100
2012-06-01 00:15:00     150
2012-06-01 00:30:00     120
2012-06-01 01:00:00     220
2012-06-01 01:15:00      80
...and so on.
```

I need a new column `df['weekday']` with the respective weekday/day-of-week of the timestamps.

How can I get this?

Answer (score 119, accepted):

Use the new [`dt.dayofweek`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.dayofweek.html#pandas-series-dt-dayofweek) property:

```
In [2]:

df['weekday'] = df['Timestamp'].dt.dayofweek
df
Out[2]:
            Timestamp  Value  weekday
0 2012-06-01 00:00:00    100        4
1 2012-06-01 00:15:00    150        4
2 2012-06-01 00:30:00    120        4
3 2012-06-01 01:00:00    220        4
4 2012-06-01 01:15:00     80        4
```

In the situation where the `Timestamp` is your index you need to reset the index and then call the `dt.dayofweek` property:

```
In [14]:

df = df.reset_index()
df['weekday'] = df['Timestamp'].dt.dayofweek
df
Out[14]:
            Timestamp  Value  weekday
0 2012-06-01 00:00:00    100        4
1 2012-06-01 00:15:00    150        4
2 2012-06-01 00:30:00    120        4
3 2012-06-01 01:00:00    220        4
4 2012-06-01 01:15:00     80        4
```

Strangely if you try to create a series from the index in order to not reset the index you get `NaN` values as does using the result of `reset_index` to call the `dt.dayofweek` property without assigning the result of `reset_index` back to the original df:

```
In [16]:

df['weekday'] = pd.Series(df.index).dt.dayofweek
df
Out[16]:
                     Value  weekday
Timestamp                          
2012-06-01 00:00:00    100      NaN
2012-06-01 00:15:00    150      NaN
2012-06-01 00:30:00    120      NaN
2012-06-01 01:00:00    220      NaN
2012-06-01 01:15:00     80      NaN
In [17]:

df['weekday'] = df.reset_index()['Timestamp'].dt.dayofweek
df
Out[17]:
                     Value  weekday
Timestamp                          
2012-06-01 00:00:00    100      NaN
2012-06-01 00:15:00    150      NaN
2012-06-01 00:30:00    120      NaN
2012-06-01 01:00:00    220      NaN
2012-06-01 01:15:00     80      NaN
```

**EDIT**

As pointed out to me by user @joris you can just access the `weekday` attribute of the index so the following will work and is more compact:

`df['Weekday'] = df.index.weekday`

Answer (score 8):

If the `Timestamp` column is a `datetime` value, then you can just use:
`df['weekday'] = df['Timestamp'].apply(lambda x: x.weekday())`

or

`df['weekday'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timestamp']).apply(lambda x: x.weekday())`

Answer (score 8):

You can get with this way:

```
import datetime
df['weekday'] = pd.Series(df.index).dt.day_name()
```

Answer (score 3):

As of pandas 1.1.0 dt.dayofweek is deprecated, so instead of:

```
df['weekday'] = df['Timestamp'].dt.dayofweek
```

from @EdChum and @Artyom Krivolapov

you can now use:

```
df['weekday'] = df['Timestamp'].dt.isocalendar().day
```

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody else has the same issue with a multiindexed dataframe, here is what solved it for me, based on @joris solution:

```
df['Weekday'] = df.index.get_level_values(1).weekday
```

for me date was the `get_level_values(1)` instead of `get_level_values(0)`, which would work for the outer index.