# Create a day-of-week column

Tags: python, datetime, pandas

Create a day-of-week column in a Pandas dataframe using Python

I’d like to read a csv file into a pandas dataframe, parse a column of dates from string format to a date object, and then generate a new column that indicates the day of the week.

This is what I’m trying:

What I’d like to do is something like:

```
import pandas as pd

import csv

df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', parse_dates=['date']))

df['day-of-week'] = df['date'].weekday()


AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'weekday'
```

Comment: Are you wanting the integer day of the week or the string name? for the former `df['date'].dt.dayofweek` will work

Comment: An integer.  And thanks for the formatting comment as well.

Comment: There is also `dt.weekday` which is the same as `dayofweek` but 2 characters shorter to type

Answer (score 195, accepted):

### Pandas 0.23+

Use [`pandas.Series.dt.day_name()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.day_name.html), since [`pandas.Timestamp.weekday_name`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Timestamp.weekday_name.html) has been deprecated:

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'my_dates':['2015-01-01','2015-01-02','2015-01-03'],'myvals':[1,2,3]})
df['my_dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['my_dates'])

df['day_of_week'] = df['my_dates'].dt.day_name()
```

Output:

```
    my_dates  myvals day_of_week
0 2015-01-01       1    Thursday
1 2015-01-02       2      Friday
2 2015-01-03       3    Saturday
```

### Pandas 0.18.1+

As user jezrael points out below, `dt.weekday_name` was added in version 0.18.1
[Pandas Docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.weekday_name.html)

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'my_dates':['2015-01-01','2015-01-02','2015-01-03'],'myvals':[1,2,3]})
df['my_dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['my_dates'])
df['day_of_week'] = df['my_dates'].dt.weekday_name
```

Output:

```
    my_dates  myvals day_of_week
0 2015-01-01       1    Thursday
1 2015-01-02       2      Friday
2 2015-01-03       3    Saturday
```

### Original Answer:

Use this:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.dayofweek.html

See this:

[Get weekday/day-of-week for Datetime column of DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28009370/get-weekday-for-datetime-in-pandas-dataframe)

If you want a string instead of an integer do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'my_dates':['2015-01-01','2015-01-02','2015-01-03'],'myvals':[1,2,3]})
df['my_dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['my_dates'])
df['day_of_week'] = df['my_dates'].dt.dayofweek

days = {0:'Mon',1:'Tues',2:'Weds',3:'Thurs',4:'Fri',5:'Sat',6:'Sun'}

df['day_of_week'] = df['day_of_week'].apply(lambda x: days[x])
```

Output:

```
    my_dates  myvals day_of_week
0 2015-01-01       1       Thurs
1 2015-01-02       2         Fri
2 2015-01-01       3       Thurs
```

Comment: Liam, I've imported the datetime module as dt, but I'm receiving this new error.  Do you know what's going on?  Thanks again!

`df['day_of_week'] = df[‘my_dates'].dt.dayofweek`


AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'dt'

Comment: When you run `df.dtypes` do you get `my_dates    datetime64[ns]`?

Comment: Yes, I get = datetime64[ns]  for my date column.

Comment: Strange.  What do you get when you run `pd.__version__` (AKA, what version are you on?)

Comment: @JamesEaves the `dt` accessor was added in `0.15.0` can you upgrade?

Comment: Yes, i updated and it works perfectly. Thank you all for your help!

Comment: Now that is a nifty use of the lambdas

Comment: The string names aren't built in somewhere?

Comment: answering self: `from calendar import day_abbr` and then `data.index = [day_abbr[x] for x in data.index]`

Comment: @LiamFoley I updated your answer with the latest API updates. Hope you do not mind. Feel free to revert it if you want. I thought it would be good to have an updated answer as the most voted. ^^

Comment: I suggest following optimization to make the result more memory-efficient:
`df['day_of_week'] = df['my_dates'].dt.day_name().astype('category')` - ie. 'cast' the series to the category type, as this consumes much less memory than the original strings.

Answer (score 16):

Use [`dt.day_name`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.day_name.html):

```
print df
    my_dates  myvals
0 2015-01-01       1
1 2015-01-02       2
2 2015-01-03       3

print df.dtypes
my_dates    datetime64[ns]
myvals               int64
dtype: object

df['day_of_week'] = df['my_dates'].dt.day_name()
print df
    my_dates  myvals day_of_week
0 2015-01-01       1    Thursday
1 2015-01-02       2      Friday
2 2015-01-03       3    Saturday
```

Another solution with [`assign`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.assign.html):

```
print df.assign(day_of_week = df['my_dates'].dt.day_name())
    my_dates  myvals day_of_week
0 2015-01-01       1    Thursday
1 2015-01-02       2      Friday
2 2015-01-03       3    Saturday
```

Comment: This is [`dt.day_name`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.day_name.html) now (since 0.23.0)

Answer (score 11):

```
df =df['Date'].dt.dayofweek
```

`dayofweek` is in numeric format

Answer (score 8):

Using `dt.weekday_name` is [deprecated since `pandas 0.23.0`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.Timestamp.weekday_name.html), instead, use [`dt.day_name()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.day_name.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'my_dates':['2015-01-01','2015-01-02','2015-01-03'],'myvals':[1,2,3]})
df['my_dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['my_dates'])

df['my_dates'].dt.day_name()

0    Thursday
1      Friday
2    Saturday
Name: my_dates, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 5):

Just in case if .dt doesn't work for you. Trying .DatetimeIndex might help. Hope the code and our test result here help you fix it. Regards,

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2015-01-01','2015-01-02','2015-01-03'],'Number':[1,2,3]})

df['Day'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Date']).day_name() # week day name
df.head()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## When date is the index

…and only the first three letters are required:

```
df['day'] = df.index.day_name().str[:3]
```

Answer (score 0):

`data['Day_Of_Week'] = pd.DatetimeIndex(data['Birth_Date']).day_name()`

Command appends new column/feature as data['Day_Of-Week'] from data['Birth_Date'] column which is present in dataset/csv previously.