# Fill the missing date values in a Pandas Dataframe column

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, time-series

I'm using Pandas to store stock prices data using Data Frames. There are 2940 rows in the dataset. The Dataset snapshot is displayed below:

[image]

The time series data does not contain the values for Saturday and Sunday. Hence missing values have to be filled. 

Here is the code I've written but it is not solving the problem:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
os.chdir('C:/Users/Admin/Analytics/stock-prices')

data  = pd.read_csv('stock-data.csv')

# PriceDate Column - Does not contain Saturday and Sunday stock entries
data['PriceDate'] =  pd.to_datetime(data['PriceDate'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
data = data.sort_index(by=['PriceDate'], ascending=[True])


# Starting date is Aug 25 2004
idx = pd.date_range('08-25-2004',periods=2940,freq='D')


data = data.set_index(idx)
data['newdate']=data.index
newdate=data['newdate'].values   # Create a time series column   


data = pd.merge(newdate, data, on='PriceDate', how='outer')
```

**How to fill the missing values for Saturday and Sunday?**

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think you can use [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html) with [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tseries.resample.Resampler.ffill.html) or [`bfill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.tseries.resample.Resampler.bfill.html), but before [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) from column `PriceDate`:

```
print (data)
   ID  PriceDate  OpenPrice  HighPrice
0   1  6/24/2016          1          2
1   2  6/23/2016          3          4
2   2  6/22/2016          5          6
3   2  6/21/2016          7          8
4   2  6/20/2016          9         10
5   2  6/17/2016         11         12
6   2  6/16/2016         13         14
```

```
data['PriceDate'] =  pd.to_datetime(data['PriceDate'], format='%m/%d/%Y')
data = data.sort_values(by=['PriceDate'], ascending=[True])
data.set_index('PriceDate', inplace=True)
print (data)
            ID  OpenPrice  HighPrice
PriceDate                           
2016-06-16   2         13         14
2016-06-17   2         11         12
2016-06-20   2          9         10
2016-06-21   2          7          8
2016-06-22   2          5          6
2016-06-23   2          3          4
2016-06-24   1          1          2

data = data.resample('D').ffill().reset_index()
print (data)
   PriceDate  ID  OpenPrice  HighPrice
0 2016-06-16   2         13         14
1 2016-06-17   2         11         12
2 2016-06-18   2         11         12
3 2016-06-19   2         11         12
4 2016-06-20   2          9         10
5 2016-06-21   2          7          8
6 2016-06-22   2          5          6
7 2016-06-23   2          3          4
8 2016-06-24   1          1          2
```

---

```
data = data.resample('D').bfill().reset_index()
print (data)
   PriceDate  ID  OpenPrice  HighPrice
0 2016-06-16   2         13         14
1 2016-06-17   2         11         12
2 2016-06-18   2          9         10
3 2016-06-19   2          9         10
4 2016-06-20   2          9         10
5 2016-06-21   2          7          8
6 2016-06-22   2          5          6
7 2016-06-23   2          3          4
8 2016-06-24   1          1          2
```

Comment: When using bfill( ).reset_index( ), the following TypeError is displayed:

Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'RangeIndex'

Comment: You need set index from column `PriceDate` - `data.set_index('PriceDate', inplace=True)`.

Comment: I am not sure if understand correctly - do you need set new column - `data['new'] = data['PriceDate']` ?

Comment: No, I actually got the solution.
Wanted the corresponding dayname of data['PriceDate'] without repetition.
This is not related to this particular question.

Found the solution to print the daynames without repetition over here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30222533/create-a-day-of-week-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe-using-python

Comment: @jezrael Any ideas on how to implement this when your data contains hundreds of different IDs? For example, I have time series data for 300 buildings and need to fill in time gaps for each as individual time series. I have written a function by hand which seems to work on small datasets but it's extremely slow.

Comment: @RenelChesak - You need `data = data.groupby('ID').resample('D').ffill().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).reset_index()`