# How to fill missing date in timeSeries

Tags: python, pandas

Here's what my data looks like:

[image: my data looks like this]

There are daily records, except for a gap from 2017-06-12 to 2017-06-16.

```py
df2['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df2['timestamp'] = df2['timestamp'].map(lambda x: 
datetime.datetime.strftime(x,'%Y-%m-%d'))
df2 = df2.convert_objects(convert_numeric = True)
df2 = df2.groupby('timestamp', as_index = False).sum()
```

I need to fill this missing gap and others with values for all fields (e.g. `timestamp`, `temperature`, `humidity`, `light`, `pressure`, `speed`, `battery_voltage`, etc...).

How can I accomplish this with Pandas?

This is what I have done before

```
weektime = pd.date_range(start = '06/04/2017', end = '12/05/2017', freq = 'W-SUN')
df['week'] = 'nan'
df['weektemp'] = 'nan'
df['weekhumidity'] = 'nan'
df['weeklight'] = 'nan'
df['weekpressure'] = 'nan'
df['weekspeed'] = 'nan'
df['weekbattery_voltage'] = 'nan'

for i in range(0,len(weektime)):
    df['week'][i+1] = weektime[i]
    df['weektemp'][i+1] = df['temperature'].iloc[7*i+1:7*i+7].sum()
    df['weekhumidity'][i+1] = df['humidity'].iloc[7*i+1:7*i+7].sum()
    df['weeklight'][i+1] = df['light'].iloc[7*i+1:7*i+7].sum()
    df['weekpressure'][i+1] = df['pressure'].iloc[7*i+1:7*i+7].sum()
    df['weekspeed'][i+1] = df['speed'].iloc[7*i+1:7*i+7].sum()
    df['weekbattery_voltage'][i+1] = 
df['battery_voltage'].iloc[7*i+1:7*i+7].sum()
     i = i + 1
```

The value of sum is not correct. Cause the value of 2017-06-17 is a sum of 2017-06-12 to 2017-06-16.  I do not want to add them again. This gap is not only one gap in the period. I want to fill all of them.

Comment: There are quite a few links about filling missing datetimes. [Here is one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38361526/fill-the-missing-date-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe-column) but there are many more

Comment: You didn't explain, what the underlying assumption is to fill missing data. All parameters except time are non-linear and change dramatically over a time course of five missing data points.

Comment: I need to sum 7 days data from each 1st data to the 7th data.(weekly) (e.g. the first data set is : df.iloc[0:6].sum[ ] and the second data set is df.iloc[7:13].sum() and so on ). If the date time have a gap, the value of the sum will be wrong, and others are incorrect as well.

Comment: Your data point will be wrong anyhow, because you will have a data point that consists to 6/7th of pure guessing. It is better to make clear that a data point is missing than to pretend an invented data point reflects reality. Exception would be that you can justify, how to predict the missing values. But look at the `pressure` data points for instance. Will they rise in a linear fashion in the missing week? Will they rise abruptly at the beginning or the end of the missing week? You don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function I wrote that might be helpful to you. It looks for inconsistent jumps in time and fills them in. After using this function, try using a linear interpolation function (pandas has a good one) to fill in your null data values. Note: Numpy arrays are much faster to iterate over and manipulate than Pandas dataframes, which is why I switch between the two.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data_arr = np.array(your_df)
periodicity = 'daily'

def fill_gaps(data_arr, periodicity):
    rows = data_arr.shape[0]
    data_no_gaps = np.copy(data_arr) #avoid altering the thing you're iterating over
    data_no_gaps_idx = 0

    for row_idx in np.arange(1, rows): #iterate once for each row (except the first record; nothing to compare)
        oldtimestamp_str = str(data_arr[row_idx-1, 0]) 
        oldtimestamp = np.datetime64(oldtimestamp_str)  

        currenttimestamp_str = str(data_arr[row_idx, 0])
        currenttimestamp = np.datetime64(currenttimestamp_str)

        period = currenttimestamp - oldtimestamp

        if period != np.timedelta64(900,'s') and period != np.timedelta64(3600,'s') and period != np.timedelta64(86400,'s'):                                
            if periodicity == 'quarterly':
                desired_period = 900
            elif periodicity == 'hourly':
                desired_period = 3600
            elif periodicity == 'daily':
                desired_period = 86400

            periods_missing = int(period / np.timedelta64(desired_period,'s'))
            for missing in np.arange(1, periods_missing):
                new_time_orig = str(oldtimestamp + missing*(np.timedelta64(desired_period,'s')))
                new_time = new_time_orig.replace('T', ' ')
                data_no_gaps = np.insert(data_no_gaps, (data_no_gaps_idx + missing), 
                                 np.array((new_time, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan)), 0) # INSERT VALUES YOU WANT IN THE NEW ROW

            data_no_gaps_idx += (periods_missing-1) #incriment the index (zero-based => -1) in accordance with added rows

        data_no_gaps_idx += 1 #allow index to change as we iterate over original data array (main for loop)

    #create a dataframe:
    data_arr_no_gaps = pd.DataFrame(data=data_no_gaps, index=None,columns=['Time', 'temp', 'humidity', 'light', 'pressure', 'speed'])

    return data_arr_no_gaps
```

Answer (score 0):

## Fill time gaps and nulls

Use the function below to ensure expected date sequence exists, and then use forward fill to fill in nulls.

```
import pandas as pd
import os

def fill_gaps_and_nulls(df, freq='1D'):
    '''
    General steps:
        A) check for extra dates (out of expected frequency/sequence)
        B) check for missing dates (based on expected frequency/sequence)
        C) use forwardfill to fill nulls
        D) use backwardfill to fill remaining nulls
        E) append to file    
    '''
    
    #rename the timestamp to 'date'
    df.rename(columns={"timestamp": "date"})
    
    #sort to make indexing faster
    df = df.sort_values(by=['date'], inplace=False)
    
    #create an artificial index of dates at frequency = freq, with the same beginning and ending as the original data
    all_dates = pd.date_range(start=df.date.min(), end=df.date.max(), freq=freq)

    #record column names
    df_cols = df.columns

    #delete ffill_df.csv so we can begin anew
    try:
        os.remove('ffill_df.csv')
    except FileNotFoundError:
        pass

    #check for extra dates and/or dates out of order. print warning statement for log
    extra_dates = set(df.date).difference(all_dates)
    
    #if there are extra dates (outside of expected sequence/frequency), deal with them
    if len(extra_dates) > 0:
        #############################
        #INSERT DESIRED BEHAVIOR HERE        
        print('WARNING: Extra date(s):\n\t{}\n\t    Shifting highlighted date(s) back by 1 day'.format(extra_dates))
        for date in extra_dates:
            #shift extra dates back one day
            df.date[df.date == date] = date - pd.Timedelta(days=1)
        #############################

    #check the artificial date index against df to identify missing gaps in time and fill them with nulls
    gaps = all_dates.difference(set(df.date))
    print('\n-------\nWARNING: Missing dates: {}\n-------\n'.format(gaps))

    #if there are time gaps, deal with them
    if len(gaps) > 0:
        #initialize df of correct size, filled with nulls
        gaps_df = pd.DataFrame(index=gaps, columns=df_cols.drop('date')) #len(index) sets number of rows
        #give index a name
        gaps_df.index.name = 'date'
        #add the region and type
        gaps_df.region = r
        gaps_df.type = t
        #remove that index so gaps_df and df are compatible
        gaps_df.reset_index(inplace=True)                
        #append gaps_df to df
        new_df = pd.concat([df, gaps_df])
        #sort on date
        new_df.sort_values(by='date', inplace=True)

    #fill nulls
    new_df.fillna(method='ffill', inplace=True)
    new_df.fillna(method='bfill', inplace=True)

    #append to file
    new_df.to_csv('ffill_df.csv', mode='a', header=False, index=False) 
    
    return df_cols, regions, types, all_dates
```