# " ValueWarning: No supported index is available. Prediction results will be given with an integer index beginning at `start` "

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, data-science, statsmodels

Why we are getting this error when we predict or forecast using Statsmodels **" SARIMAX "**?.
I am just passing the start and end of Index and steps that need to take into consideration.

```
Either use the below line to execute: 

results = model.fit()
predictions= results.predict(start =train_size, end=train_size+test_size+(steps)-1)
(Or)
forecast_= results.forecast(steps=test_size-1)
```

Is there any proper way to neglect the warning message?

**

Want to understand in detail the warning. Hope will get it.

**.

Answer (score 1):

Same here - but for me there was no missing data in the index. Everything worked fine in the previous release. After I changed the indexing from a timestamp to normal, integer values the problem disappeared. Has to do with timestamp somehow.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. What I have observed in my case is, in the series of Date or Datetime data I had, some days were missing. For e.g. I am looking into support ticket volume prediction and I had no tickets on the day of Christmas hence 25th December was missing in my data. That gap caused the issue. So, I took my start date and tried to put all dates in scope, in Excel (you mention 2 or 3 consecutive days and then drag down the column, easy) and found that I had total 5 days missing. Once I used the suggestion provided in below link, I got out of the problem.

[Fill the missing date values in a Pandas Dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38361526/fill-the-missing-date-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe-column)

Note: Once you do the ffill or bfill, the date index becomes another column. So, you set date index again.

Answer (score 0):

It has to do with non-integer indexes. It worked for me when I ran :

```
model = sm.OLS(y.values).fit()
model.forecast(steps = 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, there was a duplicated datetime index in data. When I removed that duplicated datetime, the warning is disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar warning using statsmodels.tsa.arima.model.
My index is sequential integers, with no missing values, when I receive the warning. Index was set of integers starting at non-zero value.

Resolution: reset_index() to start with 0, and then there is no warning.

TIL.