# How to fill missing dates with corresponding NaN in other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a CSV that initially creates following dataframe:

```
    Date        Portfoliovalue
0   2021-05-01  50000.0
1   2021-05-05  52304.0
```

Using the following script, I would like to fill the missing dates and have a corresponding NaN value in the Portfoliovalue column with NaN. So the result would be this:

```
    Date        Portfoliovalue
0   2021-05-01  50000.0
1   2021-05-02  NaN
2   2021-05-03  NaN
3   2021-05-04  NaN
4   2021-05-05  52304.0
```

I first tried the method here: [Fill the missing date values in a Pandas Dataframe column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38361526/fill-the-missing-date-values-in-a-pandas-dataframe-column)

However the bfill replaces all my NaN's and removing it only returns an error.

So far I have tried this:

```
df = pd.read_csv("Tickers_test5.csv")
df2 = pd.read_csv("Portfoliovalues.csv")

portfolio_value = df['Currentvalue'].sum()
portfolio_value = portfolio_value + cash

date = datetime.date(datetime.now())

df2.loc[len(df2)] = [date, portfolio_value]

print(df2.asfreq('D'))
```

However, this only returns this:

```
            Date    Portfoliovalue
1970-01-01  NaN     NaN
```

Thanks for your help. I am really impressed at how helpful this community is.

---

Quick update:

I have added the code, so that it fills my missing dates. However, it is part of a programme, which tries to update the missing dates every time it launches. So when I execute the code and no dates are missing, I get the following error:

> ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis”

The code is as follows:

```
df2 = pd.read_csv("Portfoliovalues.csv")


portfolio_value = df['Currentvalue'].sum()

date = datetime.date(datetime.now())


df2.loc[date, 'Portfoliovalue'] = portfolio_value

#Solution provided by Uts after asking on Stackoverflow
df2.Date = pd.to_datetime(df2.Date)
df2 = df2.set_index('Date').asfreq('D').reset_index()
```

So by the looks of it the code adds a duplicate date, which then causes the .reindex() function to raise the ValueError. However, I am not sure how to proceed. Is there an alternative to .reindex() or maybe the assignment of today's date needs changing?

Comment: your source date starts at 1 and ends with 10, however, your expected output ends on day 5

Comment: Check this post it did help me
https://stackoverflow.com/a/54517808/14566331

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pandas has [asfreq](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.asfreq.html) function for datetimeIndex, this is basically just a thin, but convenient wrapper around `reindex()` which generates a date_range and calls reindex.

**Code**

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date)
df = df.set_index('Date').asfreq('D').reset_index()
```

**Output**

```
    Date        Portfoliovalue
0   2021-05-01  50000.0
1   2021-05-02  NaN
2   2021-05-03  NaN
3   2021-05-04  NaN
4   2021-05-05  52304.0
```

Comment: Thank you, I will tick it once my reputation reaches 15 points.

Comment: I have just updated the original question, as there is a little follow-up problem. Has anybody got an idea how I could proceed?

Comment: Can you open a separate question with the issue, please provide sample input, sample output and error stack trace and your code in the question. U can link this question to the new question if you want.

Answer (score 1):

Pandas has [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) method: given a list of indices, it remains only indices from list.

In your case, you can create all the dates you want, by `date_range` for example, and then give it to `reindex`. you might needed a simple set_index and reset_index, but I assume you don't care much about the original index.

Example:

```py
df.set_index('Date').reindex(pd.date_range(start=df['Date'].min(), end=df['Date'].max(), freq='D')).reset_index()
```

On first we set 'Date' column as index. Then we use reindex, it full list of dates (given by date_range from minimal date to maximal date in 'Date' column, with daily frequency) as new index. It result nans in places without former value.

Comment: For this solution I get the following Error:


TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.date'

Comment: well I guess I (falsely assumed) you work with type pd.Timedelta, while the type of Date is actually string in your case. You should parse it first to be different type: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it to convert it into a datetime format. However, I thought by using date = datetime.date(datetime.now()) I would have such a format?

Comment: it is another possibility, but I'm not sure you actually change the date that way: check carefully if indeed the type has changed