# Weekday name from a pandas dataframe Date object

Tags: python-3.x, python-datetime

I would like to get the weekday name for all my date.
I have a pandas df which has a Date column formatted to datetime64[ns]

i have tried the following

```
data['Date'].dt.weekday_name
```

and I get the response

```
data['Date'].dt.weekday_name
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-207-e57074c4e346>", line 1, in <module>
    data['Date'].dt.weekday_name

AttributeError: 'DatetimeProperties' object has no attribute 'weekday_name'
```

Please help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a day-of-week column in a Pandas dataframe using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30222533/create-a-day-of-week-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe-using-python)

Comment: Thank you
`df['my_dates'].dt.day_name()`

Comment: The syntax you were trying to use `data['Date'].dt.weekday_name` is for PANDAS <= 0.22 (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22.0/generated/pandas.Series.dt.weekday_name.html)
For newer pandas versions you should use `data['Date'].dt. day_name()`

Answer (score 35):

Maybe you can use [day_name](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.day_name.html#pandas.Series.dt.day_name):

```
df['Date'].dt.day_name()
```