# how to know the day (is it Monday, Tuesday or...) of a specific date in Python

Tags: python

I have a pandas dataframe with one column called "date" with dates from 10/1/2018 to 5/1/2020 and one column called "sales" with total sales of the day. I set "date" as index and I want to have another column to show the day of the dates (e.g. Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday...). Is there any dataframe function to do that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

assuming your 'date' column is in proper datetime format (use `pd.to_datetime()` if not:

```
df['day_of_week'] = df['date'].dt.day_name()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`calendar.weekday`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.weekday):

Returns the day of the week (0 is Monday) for year (1970–…), month (1–12), day (1–31).

Or [`datetime.weekday`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.weekday):

Return the day of the week as an integer, where Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6. The same as self.date().weekday(). See also isoweekday().

For dataframe, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/55648922/1513933

Answer (score 0):

You can use  [dt.day_name](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.day_name.html) as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30222533/create-a-day-of-week-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe-using-python).

Briefly, it works like....

```py
df['day_of_the_week'] = df['date'].dt.day_name()
```