# How can I turn a date into the day of the week (as an integer)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, date

I have a pandas dataframe which has dates in the format YYYYMMDD stored as a float32. Is it possible to somehow calculate what day of the week each day is? Eg. monday = 1, tuesday =2, etc?

I don't even know where to start.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create a day-of-week column in a Pandas dataframe using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30222533/create-a-day-of-week-column-in-a-pandas-dataframe-using-python)

Comment: No since I get the following error: AttributeError: Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert the column to `str` first, then to `datetime` and use `.dt.weekday`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': [20210101, 20210102]})
df['weekday'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].astype(str)).dt.weekday

df
```

Output:

```
       date  weekday
0  20210101   4     
1  20210102   5
```

P.S. Here Monday = 0, ..., Sunday = 6, so if you want 1-7 instead, you can add 1 to column values