# Finding day of the week for a datetime64

Tags: python, numpy, datetime

Apologies if this is an easy one but I can't see anything in the `numpy` documentation. I have a `datetime64` and I'd like to find out which day of the week it is.

Unlike python `datetime`, `datetime64` doesn't seem to have a `.weekday()` function. However it does have a `busday_offset()` function, which implies it must know behind-the-scenes what day of the week a given date is. Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you could do in this way:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
t = '2018-09-19'
t = np.datetime64(t)
day = t.astype(datetime.datetime).isoweekday()
print day
```

Output:

```
3
```

Comment: thanks! - I guess this is as good as it's going to get - seems odd that the functionality doesn't exist within numpy though.

Comment: @Chrisper you're correct that it is odd, but it is a characteristic of so-called "OO" languages that they inadequately deal with polymorphism and type inference.  It gets even worse when you start dealing with "data wrangling" to get various "shapes" morphed properly, etc.  This has to take up the majority of programmer hours.

Comment: By the way, this answer doesn't work. `numpy.datetime64('2020-10-27T22:29:00.000000000').astype(datetime.datetime).__class__` is `<class 'int'>`

Comment: @user3673 - I couldn't agree more - I do most of my coding in Scala these days.

Answer (score 22):

Please look at the following related SO question:

[Get weekday/day-of-week for Datetime column of DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28009370/get-weekday-day-of-week-for-datetime-column-of-dataframe)

I understand that your data is a numpy array, it may be useful to convert your data into a dataframe format via pandas. This is shown below.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(numpyArray)
```

Provided your data is now in a dataframe, then the below code (taken from the above link), should provide you with the weekday you are after.

```
df['weekday'] = df['Timestamp'].dt.dayofweek
```

[image: Sample Output]

Additionally this reference may also assist you.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.dayofweek.html

Comment: @roganjosh - No worries. I just thought that so I started editing my answer.
Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: thanks - this definitely works, but I am using this within a loop that runs (on average) 100 000 times - so I am trying to avoid stepping into pandas-land.

Comment: @Chrisper - No worries. If I knew that, I'd suggest a lambda function you could implement which would enable this to run just as fast even with pandas.

Answer (score 13):

If you're looking for a genuinely vectorized numpy approach, you could do:

```
def day_of_week_num(dts):
    return (dts.astype('datetime64[D]').view('int64') - 4) % 7
```

It's a bit hacky, and just takes advantage of the fact that `numpy.datetime64`s are relative to the unix epoch, which was a Thursday.

(I don't know if this is an implementational detail that could change without notice, but you can always check with `assert np.zeros(1).astype('datetime64[D]') == np.datetime64('1970-01-01', 'D')`.)

Comment: thanks - that actually works very well. For a year's worth of dates, it runs about 10x faster than checking .isoweekday()

Comment: Instead of using the assertion, you can compute the shift via a known date. That is, instead of the `4` use `(np.datetime64('2020-01-06', 'D')-np.datetime64('2020-01-06', 'W')).astype(int)`. Jan 6 2020 was a Monday. Of course, this will evaluate to `4` unless `numpy` changes its behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could help. It takes a pandas series or data frame column as an input and returns a dictionary having the desired attributes for all unique DATETIME values in the target series/column.

```
def compute_dateparts(fld):
  fld_dtype = type(fld[0])
  fld = fld.unique()
  if isinstance(fld_dtype, pd.core.dtypes.dtypes.DatetimeTZDtype):
    fld_dtype = np.datetime64
  if not np.issubdtype(fld_dtype, np.datetime64):
    fld = pd.to_datetime(fld, infer_datetime_format=True)

  out = dict()
  for attr in ['Dayofweek', 'Is_month_end', 'Is_month_start','Is_quarter_end', 'Is_quarter_start', 'Is_year_end', 'Is_year_start']:
    out[attr] = pd.Series(getattr(fld, attr.lower()),index=fld).to_dict()

  return out
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple and practial way to get the day of the week and the start and end date of any week in a year, directly using np.datetime64 and np.timedelta64

```
def dayofweek(d):
    """Return dayofweek (0..7)."""
    d = np.datetime64(d) # d can be string or np.datetime64
    return  int((d - np.datetime64('1969-12-29', 'D')) / np.timedelta64(1, 'D') % 7)

def week(yr, wk):
    """return start and end date of given week in given year."""
    if wk > 53:
        yr, wk = wk, yr # in case you forgot order of yr and wk
    d = np.datetime64(str(yr), 'D') + (wk - 1) * np.timedelta64(7, 'D')
    week_start = d - dayofweek(d)
    week_end = week_start + np.timedelta64(6, 'D')
    return week_start, week_end
```