# Dates in DataFrame to Weekday

Tags: python, dataframe, datetime

I want to transform my DataFrame with dates to the specific weekday.

```
df=
    Date
0   2019-09-05
1   2018-09-07
2   2017-09-02
```

Another column now should say e.g. Monday, Tuesday etc. for each day. How can I run this method in a Dataframe?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I get the day of week given a date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847213/how-do-i-get-the-day-of-week-given-a-date)

Comment: @minfetli, This question may already have an answer here !   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28009370/get-weekday-day-of-week-for-datetime-column-of-dataframe

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following using [pandas.Series.dt.day_name](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.day_name.html)

```
df['Day'] = df['Date'].dt.day_name()
```

Giving output:

```
>>> df
        Date       Day
0 2019-09-05  Thursday
1 2018-09-07    Friday
2 2017-09-02  Saturday
```

Answer (score 0):

As another option you can convert dates to day name using [.strftime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html)

```
df['Day'] = df['Date'].strftime('%A')
```

Please, note that dates must be in datetime format to perform this.

You can also find Python's strftime directives [here](https://strftime.org/)